# doesn't parse xml when it's a single node

Tags: xml, apache-flex, actionscript-3, httpservice

my `script.php` returns this XML

```
<all>
  <item>
     <field1>value1</field1>
     <field2>value2</field2>
  </item>

  <item>
     <field1>value1</field1>
     <field2>value2</field2>
  </item>
</all>
```

The `HTTPService` uses the default `resultFormat="object"` but I don't declare it since it's the default.

Then I bind it to a `List`

```
dataProvider="{getDataHTTP.lastResult.all.item}"
```

**I get no problems when the number of `item` returned is more than 1. But when it's only 1 `item` I get an error cannot convert XMLList to mx.collections.IList.**

I tried different solutions including trying to cast it as `XMLListCollection` but it still gives an error for single items. Does anyone know of a way to possibly solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `resultFormat="xml"` and set `dataProvider="{getDataHTTP.lastResult.item}"`

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. When I do that I get no output at all, even in the case of multiple `item`. Pulling my hair on it.

Comment: @tag try `resultFormat="e4x"`

Comment: @tag: I think, the problem is, that XML is not bindable. you are likely to even get a warning at runtime, that a binding couldn't be created. As Amargosh said, you need to specify the format, so that flex can wrap it into some bindable proxies.

Comment: If the `HTTPService` instance is bindable (which it'll be if it is declared in mxml - or if it has the `[Bindable]` meta tag), then it shouldn't be a problem as the `lastResult` is anyway bindable.

Comment: I doubt it's an issue of Bindable, because it works fine when the number of `item` returned is more than 1, so it's working. I get the error only when it's a single `item` returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
import mx.rpc.xml.SimpleXMLDecoder;
import mx.rpc.xml.SimpleXMLEncoder;

[Bindable]public var xmlDataObj:Object = new Object(); 

private function yourResultEvent(evt:ResultEvent):void{
var resultXml:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument(evt.result as String);
var decoder:SimpleXMLDecoder = new SimpleXMLDecoder(true);
xmlDataObj= decoder.decodeXML(resultXml).all.item;
}
```

This way you don't need to worry about changing your resultFormat to XML or e4x.